# Travis CI Subject of E-Mail notification

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I want to return the Result of my Unit Tests in the Email notification Travis send to my account. Didn't found any solution in the documentation of travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, travis-ci doesn't support customized templates for email notifications.

For other notification services such as IRC, campfire, pushover, and slack, travis can use templates (see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#configuring-irc-notifications) to output customized notifications